# Getting an innerHtml text of a tag doesn't work, but innerText is working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm unable to figure out why the below code doesn't return the value inside span tag with id "name".

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('person').innerHtml)
```

```html
My name is <span id="person">Anon</span>.
```

[incorrect output (returns undefined)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCHKo.png)

Whereas, replacing innerHtml with innerText works fine.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('person').innerText)
```

```html
My name is <span id="person">Anon</span>.
```

[correct output (retuns Anon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jys0T.png)

Comment: Use `.innerHTML` - JS is case sensitive. (I'm voting to close this as a typo.)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: thank you, it's such an embarrassing mistake. Please close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the correct result, use `.innerHTML` with all caps. Sometimes a simple typo can cause your code to become ineffective.

Comment: Thank you! This is such an embarrassing mistake.

Comment: Please don't answer questions like this where the issue is from a typo. Vote to close it as off-topic instead.

Comment: Under the tags for the question, if you have enough rep, you should see a close link.

Comment: @j08691 I don't have enough rep -- thanks for taking the time to explain!

Comment: You can see all the privileges you can earn as your rep increases here https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges